Prove that there does not exist a value $z_{0}$ on a line $\overline{ab}$ for which $f(b)-f(a)=f'(z_0)(b-a)$
Let $f(z)=z^3$, $a=1$ and $b=i$, i want to prove that there does not exist a value $z_{0}$ on a line $\overline{ab}$ (segment of straight line joining $a$ with $b$) for which $f(b)-f(a)=f'(z_0)(b-a)$.
Suppose the opposite, that for all $z_0 \in \mathcal{L(t)}:(1-t)a+tb$, $t \in [0, 1]$, we have that
\begin{equation}
f(b)-f(a)=f'(z_0)(b-a) \quad (1)
\end{equation}
as $z_0 \in \mathcal{L(t)}$, then $z_{0}=(1-t)a+tb$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$, by (1) replacing the data in the statement we have that
$$-i-1=f'(z_{0})(i-1) \implies -i-1=z_{0}^3(i-1)$$
Replacing the value of $z_{0}$ we have that
$$-i-1=((1-t)a+tb)^3(i-1) $$
if we take $t=0$ then $-i-1=0$ i.e $-1=i$ which is not true.
I'm not entirely sure if this works perfectly.
Any suggestions or additional ways to test this? I appreciate it!

$f'(z_0)\ne z_0^3=f(z_0)$.

"Suppose the opposite, that for all $z_0$": no. Suppose for contradiction that there exists $z_0$.

"if we take $t=0$ then $-i-1=0$": no. Double check your calculation.

$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(z)\iff z^2=\frac i3\iff z=\pm\frac{1+i}{\sqrt6}\implies z\notin[a,b].$

So the equation can be also written as,
$f(b) - f(a) = f'(z)(b-a) \\
\Rightarrow \int_{a}^{b}f'(t)dt = f'(z)(b-a)$
Now obviously the above statement is only true when f'(t) doesn't change in interval (a,b) and remains constant and equal to f'(z) for some z in (a,b).
That is, f(t) has to be a linear function.
So unless the function isn't linear, there won't be any such point z on line $\overline{ab}$ .
